# Vaadin ts file 100% width for LitElement

Tags: vaadin, lit-element, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I using Vaadin `LitTemplate`. So I have my `.ts file` and `.java file.`

Now I want to use an `Custom-View(LitTempalte"Standorte")`  in an other `Custom-View(LitElement"Standort")`

Thats my `standort-view.ts`. I also tried to add `width:100% into :host` but I did not work.

```
import { LitElement, html, css, customElement } from 'lit-element';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/src/vaadin-vertical-layout.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/src/vaadin-horizontal-layout.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-text-field/src/vaadin-text-field.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-button/src/vaadin-button.js';

@customElement('standort-view')
export class StandortView extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      :host {
          display: block;
          height: 100%;
      }
      `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
<vaadin-vertical-layout style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <vaadin-text-field label="Straße" placeholder="Placeholder" id="standortstrasse" style="width: 100%;"></vaadin-text-field>
 <vaadin-horizontal-layout theme="spacing" style="width: 100%;">
  <vaadin-text-field label="Ort" placeholder="Placeholder" id="standortort" style="width: 100%;"></vaadin-text-field>
  <vaadin-text-field label="PLZ" placeholder="Placeholder" id="standortplz" style="width: 100%;"></vaadin-text-field>
 </vaadin-horizontal-layout>
 <vaadin-horizontal-layout theme="spacing" style="width: 100%;">
  <vaadin-button id="resetstandort" style="width: 100%;">
    Reset 
  </vaadin-button>
  <vaadin-button theme="primary" id="savestandort" style="width: 100%;">
    Speichern 
  </vaadin-button>
 </vaadin-horizontal-layout>
</vaadin-vertical-layout>
`;
  }

  // Remove this method to render the contents of this view inside Shadow DOM
  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

[image: Element-Tree]
How can I add the "width: 100%" to that `Standort-View`?

If I add it in browser it looks like I want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using shadow DOM (`createRenderRoot() {return this;}`), which means that the way you are defining styles does not work the way you intend to.

You can add a CSS selector in your global CSS:

```css
standort-view {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively, you can enable Shadow DOM by removing the override of `createRenderRoot`.